# Which is the Best Java IDE for Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, netbeans, ide

Which is the best base java IDE (eclipse, Netbean) for developing spring based application apart from IntelliJ.

I have used NetBean so far , the online documentation and google search points to only one link http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html . So does it mean we can only develop Spring MVC application.
If we start Spring MVC application , the suggestion window work very slow, also we cannot map existing classes with the bean, or cannot explore features, it only prompts bean attributes.

Also we cannot start with the application with existing source, even tried to add framework later will not work. I had recently downloaded Net-Bean 7.0 , which is latest so far, I have tried to install springs plugins for net-bean http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/808/spring-netbeans-module but it was in vain, although the post on the plug-in page says no additional plugin will be required, but while installing, it throws some error like as shown in image attached.

[image]

Not tried Eclipse yet.

I have seen IntelliJ on my friends machine. The development on it is fast and excellent, but bit expensive for personal application development.

Please suggest what to do, any less expensive but good IDE for spring.

Comment: Not sure why engineers are undervaluing the adoption of VSCode. IMO, there are 3 points why I would recommend VSCode.

1>> Spring itself recommends a VSCode extension - See second option https://spring.io/tools
2>>  Software Engineering is evolving and the back-end/front-end separation is no more there. We should pick IDEs which enable full stack engineering. VSCode is the best for JavaScript-ing. 
3>> Great contributors in the community. We can write/develop our own extensions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should definitely use [SpringSource Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts), an Eclipse-based IDE created by SpringSource themselves.

Also on the official [SpringSource channel](http://www.youtube.com/springsourcedev#p/c/7B74449D5224CC99/0/kSITVsOUvLU) @YouTube you'll find a pretty extensive 5-part introduction to using Spring & STS.

Comment: I will check this tool also, let me see how this works , is it an completely independent IDE from eclipse , that is , it is not a plugin, right ?

Comment: It is an Eclipse-based IDE which means it's a full eclipse, pre-packaged with some plugins.

Comment: Its useless. I am going to do it in intelliJ

Comment: STS is not available as of Dec 2021.

Comment: https://spring.io/tools will give you a link to the [Official extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmware.vscode-boot-dev-pack)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse should be precisely what you need.

Comment: SpringSource also provides [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/landing/best-development-tool-enterprise-java?__utma=1.2006123865.1306865166.1306865166.1306865166.1&__utmb=1.1.10.1306865166&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1306865166.1.1.utmcsr%3Dgoogle|utmccn%3D%28organic%29|utmcmd%3Dorganic|utmctr%3Dspring%20ide&__utmv=-&__utmk=89950107) that is based on Eclipse. I guess it's the new Spring IDE.

Comment: This answer adds no additional information, aside from stating an unargumented preference for Eclipse. Answer should be improved by adding specific argumentation.

Answer (score 1):

Prices for IntelliJ Idea are lower since version 10.5: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/index.jsp. Also you can use EAP versions and wait until NY/Easter/Another one sale. They have free version for open-source too.

Comment: Free version(Community) of IntelliJ doesn't provide Spring support.

Comment: @AbhayManiyar in my comment I mention "free version for open-source" that is an commertial (Ultimate) version available for developers of open-source projects, so it is not a Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should be fine. I use it, no problems yet.

Comment: I have downloaded Eclipse Helios, also installed Spring IDE for Eclipse from market places, giving a try... , the reason for which I am shifting IDEs is because I am using RAD and RSA (Eclipse) but cannot install spring IDE on them...

Comment: This answer adds no additional information, aside from stating an unargumented preference for Eclipse. Answer should be improved by adding specific argumentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts). It's a specially-configured eclipse for spring based applications